# How to prevent app from showing its update in play store using titanium backup?

Tags: stock-android

I want to use the older version of ES file explorer (the one before it became bloated). Play store always shows me update for it, and I usually update all my apps in one go. I don't want to update it, I've even selected don't auto update for ES but still it comes up in list of app requiring update. 
What i do is that I detach it from the market using Titanium backup pro. It works fine, the app is no longer in update list but when i restart my phone, play store again shows update for it. So how to prevent play store from showing me update for this?

Answer (score 6):

I'll give you a good alternative for that

If you don't want to ever update the app even after you reset your phone and reinstall it without involving the Google Play Store settings. Grab an app called APK Editor from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor). Install and run it,

1. Click on Select apk from App
2. Identify the app you don't want updated
3. Click it and chose common edit
4. Edit the package name section
5. Press done
6. Reinstall the app
7. Delete the original app

Google Play Store won't tell you any updates for it forever